# Python how to decode unicode with hex characters

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.x

I have extracted a string from web crawl script as following:

```
u'\xe3\x80\x90\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\xad\x97\xe3\x80\x91'
```

I want to decode `u'\xe3\x80\x90\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\xad\x97\xe3\x80\x91'` with utf-8.
With http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/, I can see the result is `'【中字】'`

I tried using the following syntax but failed.

```
msg = u'\xe3\x80\x90\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\xad\x97\xe3\x80\x91'
result = msg.decode('utf8')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordi
nal not in range(128)
```

May I ask how to decode the string correctly?

Thanks for help.

Comment: The string you are receiving is double encoded. It works fine without the `u` before the string. You should check the crawl script!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with

```
msg = u'\xe3\x80\x90\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\xad\x97\xe3\x80\x91'
result = msg.decode('utf8')
```

is that you are trying to decode Unicode. That doesn't really make sense. You can encode *from* Unicode to some type of encoding, or you can decode a byte string *to* Unicode.

When you do

```
msg.decode('utf8')
```

Python 2 sees that `msg` is Unicode. It knows that it can't decode Unicode so it "helpfully" assumes that you want to encode `msg` with the default ASCII codec so the result of that transformation can be decoded to Unicode using the UTF-8 codec. Python 3 behaves much more sensibly: that code would simply fail with

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

The technique given in kennytm's answer:

```
msg.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

works because the Unicode codepoints less than 256 correspond directly to the characters in the [Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29) encoding (aka ISO 8859-1).

Here's some Python 2 code that illustrates this:

```
for i in xrange(256):
    lat = chr(i)
    uni = unichr(i)
    assert lat == uni.encode('latin1')
    assert lat.decode('latin1') == uni
```

And here is the equivalent Python 3 code:

```
for i in range(256):
    lat = bytes([i])
    uni = chr(i)
    assert lat == uni.encode('latin1')
    assert lat.decode('latin1') == uni
```

You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Unless you are forced to use Python 2 I strongly advise you to switch to Python 3. It will make handling Unicode far less painful.

Answer (score 4):

1. Perhaps you should fix the crawl script instead, a Unicode string should contain `u'【中字】'` (`u'\u3010\u4e2d\u5b57\u3011'`) already, instead of the raw UTF-8 bytes.
2. To convert `msg` to the correct encoding, first you need to turn the wrong Unicode string back to byte string (encode it as Latin-1), *then* decode it as UTF-8:

   ```
   >>> print msg.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
   【中字】
   ```

Comment: WOW, so msg.encode('latin1') means turn it into byte string, It seems works!!! thank you very much!!!

Comment: @ShootingChuang Kind of sort of. :) Please see my answer and the linked Wikipedia article for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep msg as string not unicode.

```
msg = '\xe3\x80\x90\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\xad\x97\xe3\x80\x91'
result = msg.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: I had tried this before, but also failed. I got error like "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordi
nal not in range(128)"