# How do I convert hex to utf-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I want to convert a hex string to utf-8

```
 a = '0xb3d9'
```

to

```
 동 (http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0xB3D9/index.html)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex to utf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045876/convert-hex-to-utf-in-python)

Comment: @Sayse Not quite. There's a gigantic difference between a string like `'0xb3d9'` and a string like `'\xfd'`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - Potentially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40015477/1324033)

Comment: This character is multibyte. I think this problem is different from the content of the link.

Comment: Guys, sorry... It was my mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, obtain the integer value from the string of `a`, noting that `a` is expressed in hexadecimal:

```
a_int = int(a, 16)
```

Next, convert this `int` to a character. In python 2 you need to use the `unichr` method to do this, because the `chr` method can only deal with ASCII characters:

```
a_chr = unichr(a_int)
```

Whereas in python 3 you can just use the `chr` method for any character:

```
a_chr = chr(a_int)
```

So, in python 3, the full command is:

```
a_chr = chr(int(a, 16))
```

Comment: The problem is 'ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)'. This character is multibyte. I do not know how to convert multibyte to character.

Comment: That means you are using python 2. So use `a_chr = unichr(int(a, 16))`

Comment: Oh ... It was my mistake. I was stupid for two hours. haha stupid mistake